# How do I restore menu items in STEAM from the taskbar icon?

Tags: steam, menu

Using Steam in Ubuntu 16.04 and there are no drop-down menu items when I click on the Steam Icon in the taskbar using Unity.  Steam works, but just no drop-down menu items.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal window (CTRL+ALT+T):

```
cp /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/steam.desktop
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/steam.desktop
```

Then, edit line 4 "Exec" from

```
Exec=/usr/games/steam %U
```

to

```
Exec=sh -c "STEAM_RUNTIME_PREFER_HOST_LIBRARIES=0 /usr/games/steam %U"
```

Save & Close the file. Right-click on the **steam.desktop** file, select **Properties**, select **Permissions** Tab, and check the **Execute** option **Permissions** to enable "**Allow executing file as a program**".

Close the steam Properties dialogue.

Double click on the launcher to launch **STEAM**